# JAX-B Schema Repository

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

Where I work we have a large IT shop and have many schemas that have a lot of duplication.  I'm not a big fan of maintaining XML in say an XML repository (since we primarily operate in Java).  Instead of an XML repository I'm thinking that it would be easier to maintain JAX-B objects.

I'm wondering if anyone has this kind of setup where you maintain and share JAX-B objects across your enterprise.  So if someone was doing a JAX-WS service that needed to use a common object like for example Address, then they would include that common jar via a build tool that can manage dependencies.  Address in this case could be built by someone following some ISO standard or it can be an object that is internal to your enterprise that was built by a team inside your organization.

I tried doing various searches but couldn't find anything so I decided to post here to see if I can get any feedback.  If anyone could share any pros/cons that are currently doing this I would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

One of the prominent examples is the repo of [OGC Schemas](http://schemas.opengis.net/). Since these are schemas we frequently use, we've compiled them in [reusable maven artifacts](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/OGCS/Project+Goals).

I would say, you need both a schema repository as well as - if you're using JAXB - a repository of compiled schemas.

Just having JAXB compilations limits you just to one technology which is not advisable. Maybe yo'll need to employ other languages than Java (or environments which don't have adequate JAXB). Or you may also have schemas where application of JAXB is not adequate.

At the same time it is reasonable to provide standard compilations of schemas. Mostly it's sufficient and you don't need to recompile them in individual projects. However in some technology stacks (speaking SOA) you can't reuse these artifacts.